# Angular8 - Test a function that calls a array from a service

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

The function I want to test and my test so far (which does not work).:

```
canShowIt() {
  let showit = false;
  const profils = this.requestsService.userProfil;
  showit = profils.some((profil) => profil.id === this.profileDetail.id);
  return showit;
}

it('should return true', () => {
  const service = TestBed.get(RequestService);
  spyOn(service, 'userProfil').and.returnValue( of ([{
    id: 1
  }]));
  const result = component.canShowIt();
  expect(service.userProfil).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(result).toEqual(true);
});
```

Comment: Error: TypeError: profils.some is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case `RequestsService#userProfil` is a public member, there's no need to create a `spy`. You can simply set the desired value at the begin of your test.

```
it('should return true', () => {
  this.requestsService.userProfil = [{id: 1}];
  ...
```

Your existing test (without `expect(service.userProfil).toHaveBeenCalled();`) should however work, if you convert `RequestsService#userProfil` into a private member and create a [getter method](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-getters-setters/) to access it.

```
class RequestsService {

  private _userProfil: [];
    
  public get userProfil() {
    return this._userProfil;
  }

  ...
```